# Changes and testings on live web service

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-services

I have created a web service that is live for some time.

At the same time i purchased another domain where i imported and configured all the scripts/database from live web service.

Now i have 2 different domains; the one that i call LIVE and the other that i call TEST. Both domains have the same content now.

If i want to add a new feature, i code it on the TEST server, debug it and ensure that it works correctly. At the same time i write down all the changes to help me with implementation on the LIVE server.

After pushing the changes on the LIVE server i test them to check if everything is OK.

## Questions:

1) Is this procedure valid? Any suggestions on improving it?

2) The are occasions where testing involves changes in the database (for example if i make some logic changes in my registration form).

- How do i handle testing entries inside the database? Do i delete them?
- If the real data (no testing data) in a table go up until ID 40 (1,2,3,...40) and the testing entry takes the place with ID 41, if i delete entry with ID 41, then the next real entry will take the place ID 42 (since ID is auto-increment). How do i reset the ID counter after deleting the test entry? Right now i use the following: **ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1** and it works. Are there any site effects on the table i use this command? And why this works? I am setting the auto_increment to 1 not 41.
- Is there any problem if the entries in a database have gaps? (ex. ID: 1,2,4,5,.. missing ID=3)

ps: i am using PHP as back end, and MySQL (InnoDB) as my database.

Thanks in advance.

Christos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two questions to solve here: **deployment** and **migrations**:

1) Have a testing and production server is Ok, but you also need a way to deploy fast for both. There's a lot of options out there: deployer (http://deployer.org/) for example.

2) Modern frameworks like Laravel or Yii2, uses migrations for update your database changes in structure, the testing entry doesn't matter. In your case, there are tools for use migrations without a framework like Phinx (https://phinx.org/)

Comment: Good to know that there are tools that can help with what i seek. I will check them asap! Thanks!